# How to use InvokeRequired

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have the code below in vb.net, and I am converting it to c#. 
**EDIT**
Edited out irrelevant code.

but I am stuck at the one with `InvokeRequired`. I have added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and still the code completion doesn't show `InvokeRequired`. The listview is on a separate thread to the one I am calling it from, and I need to get around that using Invoke. Can you please tell me what am I missing? 
Thank you.

```
    Delegate Sub _AddClient(ByVal client As Socket)
    Private Sub AddClient(ByVal client As Socket)
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New _AddClient(AddressOf AddClient), client)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(client.LocalEndPoint.ToString)
        lvi.Tag = client
        lsvClients.Items.Add(lvi)
    End Sub
```

Comment: You might post your C# code, too ... `InvokeRequired` should be available if this is a `Form`, or a descendant of `Control`.

Comment: the c# code is almost identical,just that I cant seem to get the `If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New _AddClient(AddressOf AddClient), client)
            Exit Sub
        End If` to work

Comment: The class that's calling `InvokeRequired()` has to derive directly or indirectly from class `Control` in order to be able to call `InvokeRequired()`.
Otherwise, it will need a reference to the control on which it can call `InvokeRequired()`.

Does your class derived directly or indirectly from `Control`?

Comment: hmmm...actually there is NO other class :( maybe i was ambigous. The whole code above is an async server. No other class is calling it, i just tried to derive it from Control and still the InvokeRequired isnt availble :(

Comment: Correction @MatthewWatson .. I think you're right :) it seems to be working...i.e. the invokerequired is available after deriving the class from Control...im testing it right now to see if it works

Comment: Also, reduce your code to the relevent bits so that we dont have to read through a bunch of irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @Dan-o I removed unnecessary code.@MatthewWatson OK Now the InvokeRequired is available but now I get an error "Partial Declaration of class must not specify base classes"

Comment: Dude, if you're working with WPF, remove all references to `System.Windows.Forms`, WPF does need, nor care about that, and you'd better not be confused with classes with equal names from different namespaces and frameworks (for instance `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and `System.Windows.Control`. `InvokeRequired()` does not exist in WPF, that's replaced by `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()`.

Comment: Ah, I see you've added the "wpf" tag now. All is explained. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, if you're working with WPF, remove all references to `System.Windows.Forms`, WPF doesn't need, nor care about that, and you'd better not be confused with classes with equal names from different namespaces and frameworks (for instance `System.Windows.Forms.Control` and `System.Windows.Control`.

`InvokeRequired()` does not exist in WPF, that's replaced by `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()`.

Comment: Thanks HighCore. You have successfully fixed my problem number 2.3 million again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Delegate Sub _AddClient(ByVal client As Socket)
Private Sub AddClient(ByVal client As Socket)
    If ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New _AddClient(AddressOf AddClient), client)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(client.LocalEndPoint.ToString)
    lvi.Tag = client
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
End Sub
```

Comment: The line ListView1.InvokeRequired ONLY worked if i derive from Control using :Control , but then compilation fails... if I dont derive from Control the .InvokeRequired isn't even available. :(

Comment: What kind of control is your lsvClients? What type?

Comment: its a listview on a WPF window

Comment: +1 that comment helped me fix it with Dipatcher.CheckAccess()

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it is used:

```
protected void InvokePathDone(Task<IPath<ICoordsCanon>> task,
                              Action<Task<IPath<ICoordsCanon>>> action) {
  if (InvokeRequired)  Invoke(action, task);
  else                 action(task);
}
```

**Update for OP question below:**

`InvokeRequired()` is defined for the Control class to enable callbacks from event delegates to determine if they are, or are not, on the UI thread, and thus whether they must, or must not, perform their action under Invoke().

Comment: but thats exactly my problem. The InvokeRequired only becomes available when I put : Control next to my partial class, but then compilation still fails saying that Partial declaration must not specify base class...i'm sure i am missing something very basic here :(

Comment: See my update. Event callbacks must perform their workin the UI thread, but they may be running in another thread. Invoke required enables them to determine that status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, but again , I do understand why InvokeRequired is needed, the problem that is giving me a brainfreeze is that the InvokeRequired ONLY becomes available when i derive my class above from "Control", but when I do that compilation fails saying I cant specify a different base class :(

Comment: Multiple implemenation inheritance is not supported by C#; only multiple interface inheritance is supported.