# How to Invoke MessageBox on background thread in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, messagebox

How do I call Invoke to run MessageBox.Show on my background thread please?

When I display a MessageBox on my single background thread, it usually displays behind the main form, so to make the program usable I need to display it in front of the main form.

My current code is `MessageBox.Show(myMessageText, myTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)` without owner. This code is not called from the form itself. but from a helper class I have built outside it.

I want to add an owner to the MessageBox on my background thread, so am seeking run this code:
`MessageBox.Show(myOwnerForm, myMessageText, myTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)`

At the point I want to run this, `myOwnerForm.InvokeRequired` returns true, so I know I need to call an invoke method. But how? (If I just call this code, I get an exception, which is widely documented elsewhere). As the MessageBox should stop processing on the UI too, I want to use Invoke, not BeginInvoke.

How can I use invoke to run Messagebox.Show?

After hours looking on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I can only see partial solutions.

My app uses Windows Forms, developed in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Background threads should not do UI. If there is a need to display `MessageBox` in background thread code, it should be synchronized with the main (GUI) thread.

Comment: `it usually displays behind the main form` <--- this is because owner was not set - just set the owner and you should be okay. As @Igor mentioned, always run UI code on UI thread, there is no point to do otherwise, and there are numerous issues if you try to.

Comment: So why are you not calling Invoke() like you know you are supposed to???

Comment: @HansPassant, I do not know how to! As you can see from the title is "How to Invoke MessageBox on background thread in VB.NET?"

Comment: @Neolisk, my question is not how to set the owner, but how to run Messagebox.Show in the form which allows me to set the owner.

Comment: If you know about `InvokeRequired` how can you not know about `Invoke`? How and where do you use InvokeRequired? [SO entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580494/how-to-use-invokerequired) that may help, [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37642/Avoiding-InvokeRequired) that may help.

Comment: @pasty, just because I know one thing, does not mean I know everything else. I do not know how to run <code>Invoke<code/> - which is why I asked this question. Is not StackOverflow for people who want help doing something they cannot do? I am seeking help on how to use <code>Invoke<code/> to call a method <code>MessageBox.Show<code/> with 5 parameters, which I do not know how to do.

Comment: When it comes to WinForms and threading the terms belong together. You could have a look at MSDN: [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). IMO if you have read about one of them, you should have known about the other, that is why i am asking. I didn't meant to be rude.

Comment: Use BackgroundWorker resportsprogress to pass back the message text and keep the BackgroundWrker out of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

The [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method takes a delegate (callback function) that is called and optionally any parameters. Quote from MSDN:

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

- pack the `MessageBox` in a method
- create a delegate (method with the same signature as your message box method)
- call the delegate with `Invoke`

Example code (`Me.Invoke` can be changed to `someControl.Invoke`):

```
Delegate Sub MyDelegate(ByVal msg As String)

Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonStart.Click

    'If Control.InvokeRequired Then
    Dim parameters(0) As Object
    parameters(0) = "message"
    Me.Invoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf showMessage), New Object() {"message"})
    'End If

End Sub

Private Sub showMessage(ByVal msg As String)
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "test", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Sub
```

As many of the commentators already said, it is a bad practise to have / execute UI in / from thread (interacting with the user). If you need a MessageBox shown to the user when an event occurs in the thread, then create/use some messaging system.